# Binary to Hex Conversions

Tags: binary, type-conversion, hex

I just recently started a new programming class and I'm having some trouble with my work according to the example problems. Here are the two I'm having issues with:

Convert from Binary to hexadecimal:

`110110`

I grouped `0110` to a number of 6, and then `11` gave me 2, so isn't the answer 26? It's listed as 36 in the answer sheet(typo maybe?)

The next problem is where I'm having a large issue:

`1001 1010 1101 1. 01111`

I'm somewhat lost on the decimal point here. Do I ignore it? I grouped `1111` into 15, so F. Then `011.0` into 6, so 6. Then `1011` into 14, so E. Then `0110` into 6 so 6, and left with `10` so that gave me 106E6F? The professor said I was way off and was no help past that. Does anyone have any insight? I did a brief google search for converters(want to learn how to do it myself) and it gave me the answer 26B6F, not sure how they got that to be honest.

Again, this is week 1 and I'd like to learn this theory. Appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: When you're making the groups, you should start from the decimal point out, not the other way around. If you end up with a group with less than four digits, tack on zeros on the side furthest from the decimal point.

Comment: And just food for thought - the point is also named by the base, so if you've got a binary number, it's now a binary point, not a decimal point. Similarly, it is a hexadecimal point in a hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 1):

`11` in binary is `3` and not `2`

for your second problem: you should calculate the integer value and the decimal places (is this the correct english word?) separatly. You should always fill up with `0` till multiplies of 4, the integer value on the left side and the decimal value on the right side (in decimal 6.1 is the same as 0006.1000 for example).

`0001 0011 0101 1011` = `135B`
`0111 1000` = `78`

So the whole number is `135B.78`

I try to explain it a little bit different:

you have the binary number `1001101011011.01111`. Now you split it at the binary point into the integer and fractional part and add `0` on the opposite side of the binary point to get a digit count which is a multiple of 4. So the integer part `1001101011011` becomes `0001 0011 0101 1011` and the fractional part `01111` becomes `0111 1000`.

Comment: Ok I understand the issue I had with the first problem. Thanks. On the second, I am completely lost where you translated the problem into that new form..

Comment: You've got an extra 1 in the second half of the second problem - it should be `1000` = `78`.

Comment: I'm sorry. Is there anyway we can break this down further? the original is 1001 1010 1101 1. 0 1111, how did that become 0001 0011 0101 1011 and then the second half of 0111 1000?

Comment: the original is misleading. You should write it `1 0011 0101 1011. 0111 1`. You should start making groups at the binary point

Comment: no, `0111` is 7, not C and the `1` is after adding zeros `1000`, which is 8. The other numbers are also wrong. How do you convert them? `1011` is 11 (B), `0101` is 5, `0011` is 3 and `1` (`0001`) is 1, so 135B.78

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was lost on the part where you make the new groups and add the 0's. Now I understand. TY